# How to handle sporadic OutOfMemory error codes returned from Gdiplus::DrawArc?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

To the best of my knowledge [`Gdiplus::DrawArc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawarc(inconstpen_inint_inint_inint_inint_inreal_inreal)) is the only GDI+ function that does this.

I came to this bug having caught a sporadic error returned from that function in my production code that draws arcs. I then added some debugging code to test and sure enough my break-point hit:

[image]

I added the same values into this pseudo-code that is a small replica of my actual code:

```
    HDC hDC = ::GetDC(hDlg);
    Gdiplus::Graphics grx(hDC);
    Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(1, 2, 3));

    Gdiplus::Status status;
    status = grx.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    ASSERT(status == Gdiplus::Status::Ok);
    status = grx.SetTextRenderingHint(Gdiplus::TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);
    ASSERT(status == Gdiplus::Status::Ok);

    Gdiplus::Status stat = grx.DrawArc(&pen, 81, 27, 82 - 81, 242 - 27, (float)-49.573921259900864, (float)1.1629763045451398);
    if(stat != Gdiplus::Ok)
    {
        ASSERT(NULL);
    }

    ::ReleaseDC(hDlg, hDC);
```

And it worked just fine. I then added this into a loop that looped 100000 times and it worked fine as well.

Still I'm getting sporadic `Gdiplus::Status::OutOfMemory` returned from that `Gdiplus::DrawArc`.

Does anybody know, how am I supposed to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to figure what's going on in `Gdiplus`.  `Gdiplus::Status::OutOfMemory` isn't always a result of out-of-memory  state, but result of returning `InvalidPointer` by some resource-generating procedure down in chain. This can be cause by semantically-insane or out-of-bounds parameters given. E.g. within `LinearGradientBrush` the creation of a brush may fail because at some point `InferAffineMatrix(int this, GpPointF *points, GpRectF *rect)` finds that the rectangle area is less than "epsilon" value:

```
 rectArea = bottom * right - x * y - (y * width + x * height);
 rectArea = fabs(rectArea);
 if ( rectArea < 0.00000011920929 )
    return InvalidParameter;
```

in your case you probably should trace the reason, but it is usually something like that.

MS did some poor choices in ignoring some return statuses  and returning other ones instead, which leads to some inane error messages. Usually the only fix is to work around the issue and do no fill, render, or transform too small or malformed objects.

Comment: Thanks. I love this one `"Gdiplus::Status::OutOfMemory isn't always a result of out-of-memory state"` ... Must love MSFT :) So what you're saying is that I should simply ignore it. Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: @c00000fd in some cases ignoring may case worse problems.  I think, in  your case it cause by fact that your arc is practically a straight line - bounding rect is one pixel wide? Proper way is work around it.. if you check public code, you'll find that `DrawArc` does alot of things, including memory reallocation and creation of area fills - all for nothing in this case. Shouldn't one draw a line in this case?

Comment: What I'm using it in is a vector graphics type app. (Kinda like what Adobe Illustrator lets you do.) So what you see here is just a snapshot of an arbitrary arc what was drawn by a user using a mouse. (When that API caused an error.) So I really don't understand how else I can process that error message, or what shall I do differently (aside from writing my own arc function, I guess.)

Comment: @c00: Since you now know one possible reason, why the call returns an out-of-memory error code (i.e. running into numeric limits), you should probably revise your question and extract a [mcve]. Sounds like an issue that others probably have run into, or are about to, but don't know yet. Could well be a question with more value than the current score suggests.

Comment: @IInspectable: well I'm not the one who votes things down here. Plus, as I said above, I can't make a reproducible example. It's a sporadic issue. At this point I'm going to do this on the `Graphics::DrawArc` and `GraphicsPath::AddArc` functions that seem to exhibit this: `bool bResult = status == Gdiplus::Ok || status == Gdiplus::Status::OutOfMemory` until someone comes up with a better workaround (aside from posting programming platitudes.) This seems to work fine (i.e. draw the arc) even if the function returns `OutOfMemory`. We may chalk it up to MSFT inability to write non-buggy code....